# Where should I set up "environment" variables in (Java) App Engine maven properties -- GAE Maven template

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Just started working on a app engine java ee app end I am seeing the following:

```
 <!-- Parent POM defines ${appengine.sdk.version} (updates frequently). -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.sdk.version}</version>
      </plugin>
```

There is multiple maven "smaller" projects but I am not seeing a parent project. Where is it being setup?

I could just hard code the version I want but was wondering if there is a "global" property file, or if i need to setup some environment variables on my mac? What is best practice?

Comment: What's your problem exactly? You want to override the version for that plugin?

Comment: You may wish to elaborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the pom.xml file you're looking at expects to have another pom.xml in a higher directory. [You can read about pom hierarchies in the Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).

This specific line is a [common pattern in our own sample applications](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/xml-api/serviceaccount-appengine-sample/pom.xml#L19), as you can see here in the [`java-docs-samples`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples) github repo sub-directory `/storage/xml-api/serviceaccount-appengine-sample/`, which is a sample app whose pom inherits properties from [the pom at the root directory of the repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/pom.xml).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.